# Constructing automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given the nonabelian group $G$ of order $p^3$ where $p$ is a prime satisfying $p\equiv1\pmod4$, that is $G=\mathbb{Z}_p^2\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p$. Let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Then $H\lhd G$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. Is it possible to construct a $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$ such that $\sigma$ does not fix any nonidentity elements of $G$, $o(\sigma)=2^r,r\geqslant2$, and $H^\sigma=H$?

An additional question is that can one deduce the automorphism group of $G$? By computational experiment I suspect $$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p^2\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p)=(\mathbb{Z}_p^2\rtimes\text{SL}(2,p))\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$$and $$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p)=(\mathbb{Z}_p^2\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}.$$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the $R$ in Aut$(R)$? a typo for $G$?

Comment: Have you noticed question 19317, which is also about automorphisms of a nonabelian group of order $p^3$?

Comment: @East Changing the number in the url to 19317 works (you do not even have to change the words...!). A link is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/automorphisms-of-a-non-abelian-group-of-order-p3).